# How to retrieve request info by request id?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When I invite my friends I get back request_ids. After that I proceed those ids to get info about users invites have been sent to and create records in my database based on user's public profile info. But when I try to get request info by request id I get error message saying "Unsupported get request" nevertheless access token is fine.

```
// create data object to be sent to FB API
var data = new Object();
data.method = 'apprequests';
data.message = MESSAGE_TEXT;
data.display = 'iframe';
data.access_token = ACCESS_TOKEN;
data.show_error = 'Yes';
data.title = TITLE_TEXT;

// call FB API
FB.ui(data, function(aResponse)
            {
                var request_ids = '';
                if (aResponse && aResponse.request_ids)
                    request_ids = aResponse.request_ids.join(',');

                if (request_ids)
                {
                    // send request_ids string to my server for further processing
                }
            });
```

Example of such broken request id: 1930910810837. Trying to get info for it like this:
https://graph.facebook.com/1930910810837?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
Please help me understand what is wrong. May it be issue on Facebook side, for example, Facebook returned broken id for some reason? Thank you!!!